# NextJS - Is there a use for getStaticProps in a CRUD app?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Simple question. I've been playing around to try to understand well the implication use of NextJS's different ways of data fetching.

In production mode, Static Site Generation is run at build time, meaning, we would always get the same data cached... right?

In a CRUD app, where interacting with the DB comes quite often, is there any use then for using `getStaticProps`? I've tried playing around with their revalidate property, but it really doesn't make the data as updated and readily available as I would like.

I'm just curious to know the implication of `getStaticProps` instead of `getserverSideProps` then. Besides showing a blog with fixed data. Even then, after creating a new post, we will need to fetch the new data, for which we should probably use `getserverSideProps` again.

PS: For instance, I noticed accessing my main page with all the data listed takes way more time with `getServerSideProps` than with `getStaticProps`. I'd like to know if there could be a blend of both to have the pre-fetch done fast, then when heading back to the page, the data can be updated then.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case. Blogs are a great candidate for SSR, as well as forums, social media posts, e-commerce sites, etc. You can set your revalidate timer as low as 1 second if you like. But you wont see the updated page until the next refresh. The first refresh will show the stale content.

If this is unacceptable for your use case then `getServerSideProps()` is your solution.

If you're planning on starting a new project, I highly recommend you check out NextJS 13's new `/app` directory, which replaces `/pages`. It's a completely new way of doing data fetching and puts server rendering first.

Also, NextJS automatically does pre-fetching when you use `next/link` to link to other pages.

Comment: But even in a blog case, if you create a new post, and want to return to your homepage with a list of all your posts, you'd like to see the newly created one figured there. So on form validation, you'd use the `useRouter` to go to the next route, but the data won't be updated with `getStaticProps` (as far as I've tried)

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps` is used for caching. all the pages are built at built time. if you run `next build` and check your `.next` folder you see that all the html files are already built and when the user sends a request, instead of fecthing and building html upon the request, your page will serve from pre-generated pages. Imagine in a blog app, every time users from different part of the world want to read a blog, your server will fetch data, parse the data and generate HTML for all of those requests. this does not make sense. when you set the `revalidate` option your page for specific blog will be newly generated and will be replaced with the old html file. do not think using `getStaticProps` for only blog pages. your about page, contact page can also be pre-generated with `getStaticProps` and this will be very helpful for big ecommerce websites.

`getServerSideProps` is used when you need to read the request object. maybe checking cookies or headers. or maybe you need to make an api request to an external api. you cannot regenerate those pages. this function runs for every incoming request